# Cookie for domain not being used for subdomains

Tags: c#, cookies, setcookie, domaincontroller

I use [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) in my app to send my user/password to a service that returns some cookies that I can later use for all my other requests. The service is located at `https://accounts.dev.example.com/login` and returns two cookies that have `Domain=.dev.example.com`. The issue I'm finding is that, in some machines (Windows Domain Controllers), these cookies are not being used when I request resources in subdomains like `https://accounts.dev.example.com/health-check`, but according to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) a cookie for a domain can be used for requesting resources to subdomains:

> *Domain= Optional*
>
> Specifies those hosts to which the cookie will be sent. If not specified, defaults to the host portion of the current document location (but not including subdomains). Contrary to earlier specifications, leading dots in domain names are ignored. **If a domain is specified, subdomains are always included.**

Do you know how to properly configure `HttpClient` to pass the domain cookies to subdomain requests?

## A bit more of details:

The cookies returned by my authentication service at `https://accounts.dev.example.com/login` look like this in the HTTP headers:

```
Set-Cookie: AK=112233;Version=1;Domain=.dev.example.com;Path=/;Max-Age=5400;Secure;HttpOnly, 
Set-Cookie: AS=445566;Version=1;Domain=.dev.example.com;Path=/;Max-Age=5400;Secure;HttpOnly,
```

Then I can query C#'s `CookieContainer` with either of these calls in normal workstations:

```
cookies.GetCookies("https://accounts.dev.example.com")
cookies.GetCookies("https://dev.example.com")
```

Both of which will return the 2 cookies like:

```
$Version=1; AK=112233; $Path=/; $Domain=.dev.example.com
$Version=1; AS=445566; $Path=/; $Domain=.dev.example.com
```

But in the other machines (the Domain Controller's) the first call will return an empty list, while the second will return the 2 cookies.

Why this difference on the behaviour of [CookieContainer.GetCookies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.getcookies(v=vs.110).aspx) depending on which machine is running the code?

My workstations are using `Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language (.Net 4.0.30319.42000)` and the DCs are using `Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter (.Net 4.0.30319.36399)`.

## The code

This is a modified version of my code:

```
public static async Task<string> DoAuth(CookieContainer cookies,
                                        Dictionary<string, string> postHeaders,
                                        StringContent postBody)
{
    try
    {
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
        {
            handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler, true))
            {
                foreach (var key in postHeaders.Keys)
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(key, postHeaders[key]);

                var response = await client.PostAsync("https://accounts.dev.example.com/login", postBody);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                
                // This line returns 0 in Domain Controllers, and 2 in all other machines
                Console.Write(cookies.GetCookies("https://accounts.dev.example.com").Count);

                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        ...
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't find an answer to this (not in [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7f7da752-8c4b-4f64-94a6-42b58991f247/cookie-for-domain-not-being-used-for-subdomains?forum=winserver8gen) either), I decided to go with the following solution, which works, but not sure if there is a proper way of solving the issue:

```
foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies.GetCookies(new Uri("https://dev.example.com")))
{
    cookies.Add(new Uri("https://accounts.dev.example.com"), new Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value, cookie.Path, ".accounts.dev.example.com"));
}
```

So, I'm duplicating the cookie for each one of the subdomains that my app should send these cookies to.

Comment: If someone finds a better solution please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue seems to be a bug in the Set-Cookie header. It seems the cause of the issue is the `Version=` component in the `Set-Cookie` header. This makes the CookieContainer fall on its face and results in the strange `$Version` and `$Domain` cookies then being sent in subsequent client requests. As far as I can tell there is no way to remove these broken cookies either. Iterating `GetCookies()` with the originating domain does not reveal the erroneous cookies.